# Dias anteriores y posteriores calendario javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

me gustaría saber cómo puedo mostrar los dias del mes anterior en mi clandario con javascript, es decir, en lugar de mostrar celdas vacías por dias que y han pasado, poder mostrar los dias del mes anterior y posterior. Ejemplo: el lunes es dia 30, el martes 31 y el miércoles dia 1. En mi calendario sólo se muestra el dia 1, y el lunes y martes aparecen celdas en blanco. Me gustaría saber cómo mostrar el 30 y el 31. Os dejo mi código en js.

```js
var actual=new Date();
function mostrarCalendario(year,month)
{
 var now=new Date(year,month-1,1);
 var last=new Date(year,month,0);
 var primerDiaSemana=(now.getDay()==0)?7:now.getDay();
 var ultimoDiaMes=last.getDate();
 var dia=0;
 var resultado="<tr bgcolor='silver'>";
 var diaActual=0;
 console.log(ultimoDiaMes);

 
 var last_cell=primerDiaSemana+ultimoDiaMes;
 
 // hacemos un bucle hasta 42, que es el máximo de valores que puede
 // haber... 6 columnas de 7 dias
 for(var i=1;i<=42;i++)
 {
  if(i==primerDiaSemana)
  {
   // determinamos en que dia empieza
   dia=1;
  }
  if(i<primerDiaSemana || i>=last_cell)
  {
   // celda vacia
   resultado+="<td class='ayer'>"+dia+"</td>";
  }else{
   // mostramos el dia
   if(dia==actual.getDate() && month==actual.getMonth()+1 && year==actual.getFullYear())
    resultado+="<td class='hoy'>"+dia+"</td>";
   else
    resultado+="<td>"+dia+"</td>";
   dia++;
  }
  if(i%7==0)
  {
   if(dia>ultimoDiaMes)
    break;
   resultado+="</tr><tr>\n";
  }
 }
 resultado+="</tr>";
 
 
 
 var meses=Array("ENERO", "FEBRERO", "MARZO", "ABRIL", "MAYO", "JUNIO", "JULIO", "AGOSTO", "SEPTIEMBRE", "OCTUBRE", "NOVIEMBRE", "DICIEMBRE");
 

 
 // Calculamos el siguiente mes y año
 nextMonth=month+1;
 nextYear=year;
 if(month+1>12)
 {
  nextMonth=1;
  nextYear=year+1;
 }
 
 // Calculamos el anterior mes y año
 prevMonth=month-1;
 prevYear=year;
 if(month-1<1)
 {
  prevMonth=12;
  prevYear=year-1;
 }
 
 //document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByTagName("caption")[0].innerHTML="<div>"+meses[month-1]+" / "+year+"</div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+prevYear+","+prevMonth+")'>&lt;</a></div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+nextYear+","+nextMonth+")'>&gt;</a></div>";
 document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML=resultado;
 document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByTagName("caption")[0].innerHTML="<div>"+year+"</div><div>"+meses[month-1]+"</div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+prevYear+","+prevMonth+")'>&lt;</a></div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+nextYear+","+nextMonth+")'>&gt;</a></div><div>"+meses[month-3]+"</div><div>"+meses[month+1]+"</div><div>"+meses[month-2]+"</div><div>"+meses[month]+"</div>";
 
}
 
mostrarCalendario(actual.getFullYear(),actual.getMonth()+1);
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>
  #calendar {
   font-family:Arial;
   font-size:12px;
  }
  #calendar caption {
   text-align:center;
   padding:5px 10px;
   background-color:white;
   
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:medium;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
   
  }
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(1) {margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: center;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(2) { display: inline; margin-top: 5px; width: 20%;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(3) {text-align: left; float: left; color: #cccccc; }
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(4) {text-align: right; float: right; color: #cccccc;  }
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(5) { float: left; width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 10px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(6) { float: right; width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 10px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(7) { float: left;  width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 14px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(8) { float: right;  width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 14px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(3) a {cursor:pointer;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(4) a {cursor:pointer;}
  #calendar th {
   background-color:white;
   padding: 22px;
   width:40px;
   
  }
  #calendar td {
   text-align:center;
   padding:2px 5px;
   background-color:white;
   font-size:20px;
  }
  #calendar td:nth-child(7) {
   color:red;
  }
  #calendar .hoy {
   background-color:grey;
  }
  
  
 </style>
</head>
 
<body>
 <center>
<table id="calendar">
<p>
 <caption></caption>
 <thead>
 
  <tr>
   <th>LUNES</th><th>MARTES</th><th>MIERCOLES</th><th>JUEVES</th><th>VIERNES</th><th>SABADO</th><th>DOMINGO</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Incluye tambien tu HTML

Comment: Ahi lo tienes, perdona

Comment: mira esto te va a guiar: https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/how-to-build-a-beautiful-calendar-widget--net-12538

Comment: Lo siento, pero eso es casi lo mismo que tengo ya @Tegito123 , yo necesito que en esos huecos que hay en blanco, aparezcan los dias del mes anterior y posterior.

Comment: claro pero revisa y ve como hace la parte que a ti no te sale bn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se porque sumas y restas al mes, pero usando tu codigo yo lo haria asi:

```js
var actual=new Date();
function mostrarCalendario(year,month)
{
 var now=new Date(year,month-1,1);
 var last=new Date(year,month-2,0);
 var primerDiaSemana=(now.getDay()==0)?7:now.getDay();
 var ultimoDiaMes=last.getDate();
 var dia=0;
 var resultado="<tr bgcolor='silver'>";
 var diaActual=0;
 console.log(ultimoDiaMes);
 
 var last_cell=primerDiaSemana+ultimoDiaMes;
  
  // Calculamos el siguiente mes y año
 nextMonth=month+1;
 nextYear=year;
 if(month+1>12)
 {
  nextMonth=1;
  nextYear=year+1;
 }
 
 // Calculamos el anterior mes y año
 prevMonth=month-1;
 prevYear=year;
 if(month-1<1)
 {
  prevMonth=12;
  prevYear=year-1;
 }
 
 // hacemos un bucle hasta 42, que es el máximo de valores que puede
 // haber... 6 columnas de 7 dias
 for(var i=1;i<=42;i++)
 {
  if(i==primerDiaSemana)
  {
   // determinamos en que dia empieza
   dia=1;
  }
  if(i<primerDiaSemana)
    {
   // celda vacia
   resultado+="<td class='ayer'>"+(ultimoDiaMes - (primerDiaSemana - i - 1))+"</td>";
  } else if (i>=last_cell) {
      resultado+="<td>"+(i - ultimoDiaMes - 1) +"</td>";
    } else{
   // mostramos el dia
   if(dia==actual.getDate() && month==actual.getMonth()+1 && year==actual.getFullYear())
    resultado+="<td class='hoy'>"+dia+"</td>";
   else
    resultado+="<td>"+dia+"</td>";
   dia++;
  }
  if(i%7==0)
  {
   if(dia>ultimoDiaMes)
    break;
   resultado+="</tr><tr>\n";
  }
 }
 resultado+="</tr>";     
 
 var meses=Array("ENERO", "FEBRERO", "MARZO", "ABRIL", "MAYO", "JUNIO", "JULIO", "AGOSTO", "SEPTIEMBRE", "OCTUBRE", "NOVIEMBRE", "DICIEMBRE");
     
 //document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByTagName("caption")[0].innerHTML="<div>"+meses[month-1]+" / "+year+"</div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+prevYear+","+prevMonth+")'>&lt;</a></div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+nextYear+","+nextMonth+")'>&gt;</a></div>";
 document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].innerHTML=resultado;
 document.getElementById("calendar").getElementsByTagName("caption")[0].innerHTML="<div>"+year+"</div><div>"+meses[month-1]+"</div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+prevYear+","+prevMonth+")'>&lt;</a></div><div><a onclick='mostrarCalendario("+nextYear+","+nextMonth+")'>&gt;</a></div><div>"+meses[month-3]+"</div><div>"+meses[month+1]+"</div><div>"+meses[month-2]+"</div><div>"+meses[month]+"</div>";
 
}
 
mostrarCalendario(actual.getFullYear(),actual.getMonth());
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>
  #calendar {
   font-family:Arial;
   font-size:12px;
  }
  #calendar caption {
   text-align:center;
   padding:5px 10px;
   background-color:white;
   
   font-weight:bold;
   font-size:medium;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
   
  }
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(1) {margin-bottom: 10px; text-align: center;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(2) { display: inline; margin-top: 5px; width: 20%;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(3) {text-align: left; float: left; color: #cccccc; }
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(4) {text-align: right; float: right; color: #cccccc;  }
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(5) { float: left; width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 10px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(6) { float: right; width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 10px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(7) { float: left;  width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 14px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(8) { float: right;  width: 20%; color: #cccccc; font-size: 14px;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(3) a {cursor:pointer;}
  #calendar caption div:nth-child(4) a {cursor:pointer;}
  #calendar th {
   background-color:white;
   padding: 22px;
   width:40px;
   
  }
  #calendar td {
   text-align:center;
   padding:2px 5px;
   background-color:white;
   font-size:20px;
  }
  #calendar td:nth-child(7) {
   color:red;
  }
  #calendar .hoy {
   background-color:grey;
  }
  
  
 </style>
</head>
 
<body>
 <center>
<table id="calendar">
<p>
 <caption></caption>
 <thead>
 
  <tr>
   <th>LUNES</th><th>MARTES</th><th>MIERCOLES</th><th>JUEVES</th><th>VIERNES</th><th>SABADO</th><th>DOMINGO</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió para los dias anteriores, pero para los dias posteriores en lugar de volver del 31 al 1 del mes siguiente, me sale el dia 63 y cosas así, no se si sabes como lo podría solucionar. @alanfcm

Comment: ya edite el codigo, tienes que jugar con los numeros, pero de la manera que lo tienes, creo que solo funcionaria para el mes actual

Comment: Consejo: usa moment.js

Comment: Tambien puedes usar algun plugin como jQueryDatePicker: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Y cómo lo podría hacer para que me funcionase siempre? Lo siento por molestarte tanto, pero me cuesta mucho esto . @alanfcm

Comment: Seria mucho mas facil si utilizaras una libreria ya existente como moment.js o jQueryDatePicker

Comment: no se podría utilizar una variable de incremento como i++? @alanfcm

Comment: Cómo podria realizarlo con moment.js? @alanfcm

Comment: Aqui hay un link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786372/creating-a-custom-calendar-with-moment-using-days-weeks-and-headings

Answer (score 0):

Vale, ya lo he solucionado, he añadido como variable var a=0 y var b= ++a, y he sustituido la línea " else if (i>=last_cell) {
      resultado+=""+(i - ultimoDiaMes - 1) +"";" por "else if (i>=last_cell) {
        resultado+=""+a+++"";}" .

Muchas gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda